# Brocade tag outdated?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a tag for the company [Brocade] with the description including "campus Ethernet switches and routers". Brocade was split up and purchased by several companies and the "campus" business was acquired by Ruckus Wireless (which was itself acquired by Arris).

Does it make sense to update the tags to reflect that? Everyone I know still calls the switches Brocade.

There doesn't seem to be a tag for [arris] or [ruckus-wireless]. Should they be synonyms with [brocade]?

Comment: Everyone here seems to still call them Brocade as well. I'm not sure any new tags are necessary.

Comment: I had a Ruckus salesperson on the phone to me the other week, trying to get me to buy Ruckus and Brocade all in one go. She still seemed to call it brocade too.

Comment: Maybe they still have inventory with the old branding.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment we have exactly four questions mentioning Ruckus hardware. There are 11 mentioning Arris, all of which are about small business/SOHO cable modems (at least, of those that are still open).

We have 87 questions mentioning Brocade equipment.

There doesn't seem to be a particular need for new tags at this point, but anyone with at least 300 reputation can [create a new tag](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/create-tags) as part of the process of asking a new question.